# PHP Extract email address from a string

Tags: php

I am using PHP.

I have a string of text like this:

```
mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com
```

I need to extract the email address from this (please keep in mind, this email address can be a million different variations):

```
smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;
```

So that I just end up with this:

```
xxxx@outlook.com;
```

How can this be accomplished? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't even know where to start, so no. Thus the question: How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You can start by [searching for](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) `'smtp.mailfrom='` in the input string. The regular expressions could help you extract the email address easily but they are not really needed in this case. A simple string processing using [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is enough here. You know that the email address is bounded by `smtp.mailfrom=` and `;`.

Comment: You can use regular expresions and preg_match function in php. Try tu find smtp.mailfrom=XXX;

Comment: Is the address you are looking for necessarily starting with `smtp.mailfrom=`?

Comment: It will always start with: smtp.mailfrom=

Comment: And it may be assumed the mailbox name never will contain a `";"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$string = 'mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com';
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string , $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: The `regex` you use is not good for email addresses. It [matches `a@-b.cd`](https://3v4l.org/IRAke) which is not a valid email address. And it does not match `a@b.c.d.info` which is a perfectly valid email address.

Comment: @axiac ,thank you i updated the code

Comment: It also catches all emails, he needs only the one in smtp.mailfrom=XXX; so I would add it to the pattern

Comment: Wow, that works amazingly. Now I need to figure out what is going on with the script, thanks!

Comment: How do you know to write this pattern: $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'; ... Is there a library of these types of reg expressions?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. It will fail a lot of times when simpler methods work just fine

Comment: The new `regex` doesn't match valid emails like `a@b-c.de`. As a side note, a `regex` that captures all the rules of valid emails is at least 5 times longer than what you provided. But there is no need for `regex` here.

Answer (score 4):

Use a double explode to find the email.

First explode on the `"smtp.mailfrom="` and use the item after (`[1]`), then on `";"` and use the first item in the array as the $email.

```
$str = "mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com";

$mail = explode(";",explode("smtp.mailfrom=", $str)[1])[0];

echo $mail;
//xxxx@outlook.com
```

https://3v4l.org/KGCVc

Answer (score 0):

I made your example work with the following regular expression:

```php
<?php

$str = 'mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com';

if (preg_match('/smtp\.mailfrom=(?<email>[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+)/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches['email']);
}
```

The expression for the email is quite complex, but I just took it from the [email validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html) of Symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/EmailValidator.php

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide an algorithm with respect of quoted characters in the mailbox name (see [RFC822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)).

I use `preg_` functions to support UTF-8 compatible encoding since `mbstring` is a non-default extension.

```
$str1 = 'mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com';
$str2 = 'mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xx"@"yy";"zz@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xx"@"yy";"zz@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com; xx=yyyy; aa=bb;cc=ddd';

foreach ([$str1, $str2] as $subj)
{
  echo $subj, PHP_EOL;

  // cut off begin of string up to 'smtp.mailfrom='
  $rpl = preg_replace('~^(?:.*?[^\w.-])?smtp.mailfrom=~us', '', $subj);

  // match found / removed?
  if($rpl !== $subj)
  {
    // split on semicolon without remove (lookahead)
    $splitted = preg_split('~(?=;)~us', $rpl);

    $s = '';  // string buffer
    $q = 1 ;  // number of quotes in buffer, mock 1 for 1st iteration

    // while $q is odd (unpaired quotes) and more chunks available, append to string
    while(($q & 1) && !empty($splitted))
    {
      $s .= array_splice($splitted, 0, 1)[0];
      $q = preg_match_all('~"~u', $s);
    }

    echo $s, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

output:

```
mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxx@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxx@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com
xxxx@outlook.com
mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@outlook.com header.s=selector1 header.b=OvtBcHsM;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xx"@"yy";"zz@outlook.com designates 12.12.12.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xx"@"yy";"zz@outlook.com;       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=outlook.com; xx=yyyy; aa=bb;cc=ddd
xx"@"yy";"zz@outlook.com
```